# What data structure would I use for sorting words based on letter frequency and position?

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I have a project that I'm working on that I'm planning to implement in both java and ActionScript, so that's why I tagged both languages.

To accomplish this project, I will need to create a set of all words from a given dictionary with a given length. Then, upon selection of a letter, I need to create subsets of the words based on BOTH letter position and frequency of the letter. For example, if the set contains

```
{this, time, pate, malt, that, teat, tote}
```

and the user selects the letter "t", I need to divide the set into subsets such that:

```
Subset 1 (t___) = {this, time}
Subset 2 (__t_) = {pate}
Subset 3 (___t) = {malt}
Subset 4 (t__t) = {that, teat}
Subset 5 (t_t_) = {tote}
```

for each subset that exists (note that (_t__) did not exist, so no subset was created).

What data structure would be my best choice for a situation like this? I am programming this for both java and ActionScript, so ideally it would be a structure that I could use for both of them. However, I am not above completely changing data structures between languages if necessary. The two programs will be separate implementations for my own practice; there is no cross-platform functionality necessary.

Some things I have considered:

Tries: Usually when I'm working with sets of words, I use Nodes with a Trie. However, I don't think that will work in this case because there is no efficient/elegant way to split the Trie into words based on position of the letters. It would be terribly inefficient to tranverse the trie for anything that has a specific letter in the third position and not in any other positions, for example. So I don't think tries will work.

Arrays: The most basic of data structures. Simple and easy to use. I could probably make this work by storing the word set as an array of strings, then use a series of comparisons using charAt() on the strings to split them into the subsets. However, this also doesn't seem very elegant, and I imagine there would be a better structure to use.

ArrayLists: A similar issue with arrays. I'm not sure that the List implementation would help with anything anyway.

Dictionaries/Maps: The only advantage to these is that I've used them before. I don't really think they fit the situation at all.

Comment: what is your own analysis so far? What are your candidates with pros and cons?

Comment: So we will have position of the letter or length of the word in `set` ? i.e What is the input we will have. ?

Comment: Updated the OP with my initial analysis

Comment: @Looser: we will have the length of the word. All words in the initial set will be of the same length (they actually get pulled from a dictionary based on their length). The input will be the character we are matching to; we will be splitting into sets based on how many of the character/what position the character(s) are in.

Comment: As of now, I'm leaning towards a Set of some time to handle the word lists. This is better than ArrayLists because with a Set I don't have to worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the data structures I used.

First, I used some HashSet to store each set of words. Sets make it so you don't have to worry about duplicated words in the list throwing off your number of words per list.

Second, I used a HashMap> to map key/value pairs.

Third, the keys were strings dynamically created by comparing each letter in the charArray of each word to the guessed letter. If the character was a match, I appended "1", otherwise "0". This left me with a key of the appropriate length composed of 1s and 0s showing both the number and position of each character.

To sort the words, I created this key for each word. Then, if the key already existed in the map, I added it to the HashSet mapped to that key. Otherwise, I created a new key value pair with a new HashSet containing the new word.

This worked great for my test sample size. I'll still need to run it for the 60000+ word dictionary after I finish the rest of my code and make sure that it scales, but it works very quickly when I'm only dealing with a few hundred.

Answer (score 0):

1. All words in a the ArrayList say elements.
2. A map which has the key as subset i.e t__*,*_t_ and Value as the list of indexes of words for each subset in the list 1 above.

Now you just need to iterate over the list:1 and populate the 2nd map.

Comment: How would using the subset as a key work? Would it have to be an array of booleans to keep track of position ie 1000 for words that start with the letter? Or would I have to dynamically create a regex to sort them out?